# paypal - on success - redirect is not working

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I created a sandbox paypal account and used IPNListener from tutorial http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html . In my code, after the verifying paypal response, trying to redirect to a dynamic url. After successful payment in paypal, it is not redirecting to the dynamic url

```
    include('ipnlistener.php');
    $listener = new IpnListener();
    $listener->use_sandbox = true;
    $listener->use_ssl = false;

    try {
        $listener->requirePostMethod();
        $verified = $listener->processIpn();
     } catch (Exception $e) {
     error_log($e->getMessage());
     exit(0);
     }
    $url1="http://www.google.com";
    $url2="http://www.ayond.se";
     if ($verified) {
      header('Location: '.$url1);
     }
     else
     {
           header('Location: '.$url2);
      }
```

Comment: @Osa added full code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're confusing IPN and PDT.

IPN happens completely separate from your checkout pages and it is server to server communication. PayPal simply POSTs data to this URL and you can process that data accordingly.  This allows you to automate tasks like database updates, email notifications, etc.

It's not something that happens within the browser session, though, so redirects aren't going to work here.

In order to set where the user will go after they've completed payment you'll need to set ReturnURL in your API calls, or the return field in standard button form code.

Answer (score 0):

check your code properly, you are redirecting to $url on success, you don't have $url you have $url1

Ok so no that you edited your code, did it work ?

Comment: can you post the code on how you are grabbing the value of $verified from paypal

Comment: are you getting anything in the verified variable or getting anything in the error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have any content before your header('Location: '.$url2); call. (aka sould be only php code before you redirect)